# Get a list of pages within a domain without a title set

Tags: google-search, title

On our webshop, we have about 60k distinct URLs and some of them don't have a `<title>` set.

I know the google parameter `intitle:` but I can't handle to find those pages using that.

Do you have a hint for me, that does not require to install a crawler or something?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Google Webmaster Tools? There is a section there labeled "HTML Improvement" which can catch stuff like missing or duplicated title or description meta tags.

See this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80407 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

*Google search limit*

Google has and will never return that many results at one time even if you clicked pages next, next, next. Most returned results are capped at 1,000 but can differ depending on the search type. It should be noted that Google often changes the title and meta description when searching so you should never use Google search as reliable way of listing titles and meta descriptions.

*Option 1 - Content Management Systems*

Most open-source content management systems such as Joomla, WordPress, Drupal, Prestashop and Magneto etc will have dozens of plugins that add SEO functionality allowing meta descriptions and titles to be seen, compared and even edited on a bulk scale (60K isn't a friendly number and no plugin will take away all the work).

*Option 2 - SQL / Json / MongoDB Output*

Depending if your site uses a database then you can [output the results using a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format), for example if your site uses MySQL then you can run a query and get returned results using the commandline, most hosts use phpmyadmin so this becomes a little bit easier, for [Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600099/how-to-output-json-data-correctly-using-php) and [MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104800/printing-mongodb-shell-output-to-file) or anything else similar will have similar methods that you can output results to a file.

*Option 3 - Spidering your Website*

Another option could be using something like [Microsys A1 Sitemap Generator](http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/), this sitemap generator has a lots of options and it should be possible to output results to a CSV file or similar. There are several other tools on the market that which will do similar. If your site is 'STATIC' and doesn't use a CMS then this option is mostly likely your best bet or using some kind of commandline tool to harvest the results of each .html file.

*Option 4 - 3rd Party SEO Websites*

There are many SEO 3rd party websites such as [MOZ](http://moz.com/products), [SEOProfiler](http://www.seoprofiler.com/) and so forth that will allow you to look at your site as a whole and review your pages. While I'm not a customer myself I do beleieve these have the option but do check before purchasing.